# How to insert a logo into the footer of an R Markdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown, graphical-logo

I am needing to insert a proprietary logo at the bottom of each document that will be produced. I have found a package named fancyhdr but it is a bit involved. Do you folks have any knowledge of inserting logos at exact places in an R markdown document?

The logo is a .png file saved on my desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply add it as an image in the last line of code.

```
![](logo.png){height='25'}
```

Just to share, I like to add my logo at the top right corner via the YAML:

```
---
title: "This is My Title<img src=\"logo.png\" style =\"float: right; width:12%\"/> "
date: "06 Nov 2020"
---
```

Comment: So does this go in the YAML section or the last line of code in R markdown?

Comment: The first solution goes to the last line. The YAML solution was provided in case you want to put the logo on the top right corner instead.